# How to retrieve value from all keys with the same name from an array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I would like to retrieve the values from keys named "termKey" from all dictionaries in an array of dictionaries (as I want to display the values in a UITableView). Any suggestions?

Here's the array of dictionaries:

```
{
  "questionData": [
    {
      "termKey": "respiration"
    },
    {
      "termKey": "mammals"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the flattened array:

```
[(key: "termKey", value: "respiration"), (key: "termKey", value: "mammals")]
```

The output I want would be something like: `["respiration", "mammals"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`compactMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2957701-compactmap) on the array and lookup the dictionary key in the closure:

```
let questionData = [["termKey": "respiration"], ["termKey": "mammals"], ["badKey": "foo"]]

let values = questionData.compactMap { $0["termKey"] }
print(values)
```

> ```
> ["respiration", "mammals"]
> ```

---

`compactMap` runs its closure for each element in the array to create a new array.  Here, we look up the value for the key `"termKey"`. Dictionary lookups return an optional value.  If the key is not present, the result will be `nil`.  `compactMap` skips the `nil` values and unwraps the values that are present.

Answer (score 1):

```
let array = [(key: "termKey", value: "respiration"), (key: "termKey", value: "mammals")]
array.map({ $0.value })
```

And you will get an array of the values that looks like:

```
["respiration", "mammals"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Decode the JSON into structs and `map` the result to the `termKey` values of `questionData`.

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let questionData : [Question]
}

struct Question: Decodable {
    let termKey : String
}
```

---

```
let jsonString = """
{"questionData": [{"termKey": "respiration"},{"termKey": "mammals"}]}
"""

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    let termKeys = result.questionData.map{$0.termKey}

} catch { print(error) }
```